In Javascript can you create a bi-directional map?
I'm trying to figure out the best (simplest?) way to create maps for all of the properties of an object of objects. For example:
const customerData = {
  customer1: {
    region: "south",
    market: "education",
    salesRep: "Bob"
  },
  customer2: {
    region: "north",
    market: "commerical",
    salesRep: "Nancy"
  }, ...
}

In my real world example, each customer has about 10 properties, each with a single primitive data type. I want to take and convert that to objects/maps that I can use to look up all the customers that have, say region == "north".
const regions = {
  north: ["customer2", ...],
  south: ["customer1", ...]
}
// OR
const regions = {
  north: [customerData["customer2"], ...],
  south: [customerData["customer1"], ...]
}

And doing that for all of the properties.
(If I weren't storing these in Redux and using the Redux toolkit, I would probably do the latter, but it prefers not deeply nesting the data, so will probably go with the former.)
I can easily write the forEach/for of loops to create these objects.
But my real question is: Is there some higher level construct for this?
This seems like this would be a not uncommon thing, but I can't think of a way of doing it without just spinning through the list of all customers and manually creating the Objects/Maps for each property.
I guess I could probably convert the customerData to an array and use .filter(), but this seems heavy (there are over 2000 customers).

You're kind-of describing a relational database.

JavaScript offers no native data structures to perform such a task. An alternative to iterating your primary collection for each query is to update the desired query views (memos) every time the primary collection is updated. You have to decide: Is that trade-off worth it? The natural data structure for your collection is a Map of key: customer ID => value: customer object.

You can streamline the process using reduce instead of manually writing loops. reduce will allow you to build those maps in a more concise and functional way.
const createLookupMaps = (data) => {
return Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [customerId, customerInfo]) => {
        Object.entries(customerInfo).forEach(([key, value]) => {
          if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = {};
          if (!acc[key][value]) acc[key][value] = [];
          acc[key][value].push(customerId);
        });
        return acc;
      }, {});
    };
    
const lookupMaps = createLookupMaps(customerData);

Which will generate a set of maps for each property:
{
  region: {
    south: ["customer1"],
    north: ["customer2"],
    //...
  },
  market: {
    education: ["customer1"],
    commercial: ["customer2"],
    //...
  },
  salesRep: {
    Bob: ["customer1"],
    Nancy: ["customer2"],
    //...
  }
}

A single pass through the data generates the lookup maps so it's efficient while also avoiding deep nesting at the same time.
There is no native JavaScript data structure that could help achieve this cleanly though.

If you need to add/remove records or change properties, running this every time, won't make it efficient.

And OP already considered going through the array to create such structure.

I would use a map instead of an object for the containers, and set instead of array. If the custormerid is stored in the object, I would add the object to the set instead of the customerid, since internally it is just a pointer, and when I get objects from the set I don't need to lookup the object from the customerid.
